# Xcode iOS Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Why am I unable to edit a View while zoomed out in the iPad storyboard, but I am able to do so in the iPhone storyboard? Is there a reason for this default setting, and can it be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I'am not able to edit the content of an view weather in the iPad nor in the iPhone Storyboard and i don't think that this can be changed very easily. I think that the idea behind this is, that you can move the views around (while zoomed out) and edit them (while zoomed in).

EDIT: You can not only move them around,.. You can also connect views, edit their classes, usw.. but you can't select specific objects on the view.